# simple Servlet CDI generating NullPointerException

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi

I am working on sample application called bookstore where I have used Dependency Injection. Very simple application. I am using JavaEE 6, GlassFish 3.1.2, Static data in a class (no db), Eclipse Juno.

***I can provide more info if needed.***

**Error I get:**

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[com.bookstore.web.BookListServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet com.bookstore.web.BookListServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bookstore.web.BookListServlet.doGet(BookListServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
```

This I know is Dependency is not injected. Class instance is not created to use it. If I remove @Inject and created an instance of a class than the page is loading fine.

*Servlet code generating error: See bold comments*

```
package com.bookstore.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.bookstore.BookRepositoryImp;

@WebServlet("/book/")
public class BookListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private BookRepositoryImp bookRepo;

    public BookListServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

                **//bookRepo = new BookRepositoryImp(); If uncommect this code and remove @Inject than page working fine**
        req.setAttribute("books", bookRepo.listBooks());
        String path = "/WEB-INF/pages/book-list.jsp";
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(req, res);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

    }

}
```

**Project structure:**

[image: Project]

Comment: Which line is the line 29? Have you tried moving your beans.xml file into the WEB-INF folder where your web.xml lives, maybe for some reason your beans.xml file is not copied properly to the resulting war file.

Comment: @kris, That worked. I moved file into WEB-INF and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: would be great if you'd marked the question as solved

Comment: I have added the answer so you can mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried moving your beans.xml file into the WEB-INF folder where your web.xml lives, maybe for some reason your beans.xml file is not copied properly to the resulting war file.